# How can I fetch the value of a key-value pair in a JSON using shell script

Tags: arrays, json, bash, shell, jq

How can I fetch the value of a key-value pair in a JSON using shell script
I do not know the positions of key-value pairs in the JSON, I will have to search and get the value of the key-value pair.

```
{
    "firstName": "Rajesh",
    "lastName": "Kumar",
    "gender": "man",
    "age": 24,
    "address": {
        "streetAddress": "126 Udhna",
        "city": "Surat",
        "state": "GJ",
        "postalCode": "394221",
        "state": "WB"
    },
    "phoneNumbers": [
        { "type": "home", "number": "7383627627" }
    ]
}
```

Sample JSON. I will have to fetch the value of the city and I do not know the position of it as I will have to search and fetch the value.

Comment: `jq .address.city input.json`?

Comment: Here's a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Comment: Does Rajesh know you're posting his address and phone number online?

Answer (score 2):

JSON objects do not have a position (well, they have in the written-out file but another order would be considered equal). Arrays do have an order.

The `city` field is located within the `address` field  of the outermost object. Therefore, using jq, you can access it with the filter `.address.city`. The `-r` option unwraps the resulting JSON string into a raw string for the output.

```sh
jq -r '.address.city' input.json
```

```
Surat
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/geSxbQczqd)

Answer (score 0):

You could get all occurrences of the values corresponding to a key named "city" by:

```
jq '..|objects|.city  // empty'
```